# Use ComboBox to Display Specific ImageList

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a program I  created in VisualBasic that is very similar to a slideshow image viewer. On the left side the user is able to select an image from a location and display it. On the right side I would like them to be able to use the combo box to select a category which would only display images in that category.

I am currently able to get an image list loaded in the right side and the user can cycle through that list, but I am having trouble figuring out how to connect the combobox and imagelist. Maybe there is another route I should try?

[image: Program Layout]

```
    Public Class Form1
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Btnnext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    btnPrev.Enabled = True
    Static i As Integer
    Dim incp As String
    incp = +1
    i += 1
    PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(i)
    If i = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1 Then
        i = -1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Btnprevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
    Static i As Integer
    Dim incp As String
    incp = +1
    i += 1
    PictureBox2.Image = ImageList1.Images(i)
    If i = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1 Then
        i = -incp
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What exactly does *"images in that category"* mean? How exactly is the relationship between category and image represented?

Comment: Please provide minimum code which shows your issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have microscope pictures of different types of pigments: aluminum and mica. For example, a user selects 'aluminum' and only the images in the aluminum image list are displayed.

Comment: @Hostel Here is the code if helpful, I've don it all through visual basic.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that you have multiple `ImageList` objects and you want the user to select one using the `ComboBox`? If so then you do it like you would for selecting from any other list of objects using a `ComboBox`, e.g.

```vb
category1ImageList.Tag = "Category 1"
category2ImageList.Tag = "Category 2"

categoriesComboBox.DisplayMember = "Tag"
categoriesComboBox.DataSource = {category1ImageList, category2ImageList}
```

The user selects from the `Tag` values and then the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` is the selected `ImageList`.